# Regex Replace Character combinations

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio

I'am trying to filter a string using Regex, I want to filter the `PÑ` combination out of my string, and also some Seperate `P`'s, However in the string that gets provided are also some parts of text like: `PB00121324`, I want to keep that `P`.

this is the string:

```
PB014EC8F;1359300102;NL1200000001 ;Ey³ PÑ PÑ B014EC8F;1359 P B014EC8F;1359
```

I want to filter out: seperate `P`'s and `PÑ`'s

So that the output would be this:

```
PB014EC8F;1359300102;NL1200000001 ;Ey³
```

I'am now using this code:

```
string CleanString = Regex.Replace(DirtyString, @"[\\PÑ?]", "");
```

The problem is that it will result this:

```
B014EC8F;1359300102;NL1200000001 ;Ey³
```

instead of this:

```
PB014EC8F;1359300102;NL1200000001 ;Ey³
```

Does anybody know the Regex for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "some Seperate P's"? Where in that example string is there a P that you want to remove that is not followed by an Ñ?

Comment: It is not in the Example, but sometimes, the string I get is filled with random seperate P's, like B014EC8F;1359 P B014EC8F;1359

Comment: I'd suggest you to edit your post to include more examples and what should be the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\b` to find a word boundary so for example the regex `\bP\b` will find a `P` in isolation.

With `\bP\b`...

Input `Hello P Goodbye` -> `P` Matches as it is adjacent to spaces (non-word characters)

Input `HelloP Goodbye` -> `P` does not match as it is adjacent to the previous word

Input `Hello.P.Hello` -> `P` matches as it is adjacent to non-word characters

Input `P Hello` -> `P` matches as it is adjacent to the start of the string and a space.

In response to your comment below - If the first regex `[..]` is intended to find two full-stops/periods then this is *not* what it will do. `[]` denotes a character class and providing duplicate characters in a character class is meaningless. To match two full-stops use `\.\.`

I'm not sure if combining into one regex is possible as the order of execution is very important...

`Hello..P..S` is a P in isolation. However after removal of `..` we have `HelloPS` which is not a P in isolation. To combine multiple replace is easy but they will all effectively happen 'at the same time' whereas your current method is doing one, then the next, then the next. ie - The input is different on each occasion.

However to combine the replaces you would do...

```
 string cleanData = 
 Regex.Replace(DisplayText, @"(\.\.|\bPÑ?\b| )", ""); //untested :)
```

[Sort of demo](http://rubular.com/r/EN8ehllq5w)

Comment: Thanks, do you perhaps know a way to convert all this Regex's to one?                                                            string cleanData = Regex.Replace(DisplayText, @"\[..\]", "");
string evenCleanerData = Regex.Replace(cleanData, @"[\\Ñ?]", "");
            string cleanestData = Regex.Replace(evenCleanerData, @"\bP\b", "");
string uberclean = Regex.Replace(cleanestData, " ", "");

Comment: What is the first regex intended to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression:

```
\bPÑ?\b
```

Input:

```
PB014EC8F;1359300102;NL1200000001 P ;Ey³ PÑ PÑ
```

Output:

```
PB014EC8F;1359300102;NL1200000001  ;Ey³
```